# multiple instances of Console app running on same computer with same connection string max pool size reached - Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, connection-pooling

When I run 2 instances of the app on the same machine I get this error:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Pooled connection request timed out
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
```

From what I've been reading the connection pool is per process so the 2 instances shouldn't share the connection pool even though they have the same connection string.

I've been looking at V$SESSION and I can see the max number of connections but they are Inactive and Waiting. When Connection.Open() is called I would expect to use one of those, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: My guess there is something wrong with your code

Comment: V$SESSION will only show a session as `ACTIVE` if that session is actually processing a SQL request in the exact moment in time that you run a query on it. 99.9% of the time, most sessions will show as `INACTIVE`; that doesn't mean they aren't valid or current. If the total number of sessions shown is the max allowed, then your app does have too many connections.

Comment: @pmdba Thanks! I just don't get why when I run them in parallel one will reach the max pool size

Comment: It sounds like connections aren't being returned to the pool when they're no longer in use. I suspect TheGeneral is right and there is an issue with your code.

Comment: @TheGeneral I agree but how should I approach it? What should I be looking for. So far I've been checking if all connection are closed.